# Multiple service connections vs internal routing in MMO

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, scalability

The server consists of several services with which a user interacts: profiles, game logics, physics.

I heard that it's a bad practice to have multiple client connections to the same server.

I'm not sure whether I will use UDP or TCP.

The services are realtime, they should reply as fast as possible so I don't want to include any additional rerouting if there are no really important reasons. So are there any reasons to rerote traffic through one external endpoint service to specific internal services in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be multiple questions in one package. I will try to answer the ones I can identify as separate...

UDP vs TCP: You're saying "real-time", this usually means UDP is the right choice. However, that means having to deal with lost packets and possible re-ordering of packets. But, using UDP leaves a couple of possible delay-decreasing tricks open.

Multiple connections from a single client to a single server: This consumes resources (end-points, as it were) on both the client (probably ignorable) and on the server (possibly a problem, possibly ignorable). The advantage of using separate connections for separate concerns (profiles, physics, ...) is that when you need to separate these onto separate servers (or server farms), you don't need to update the clients, they just need to connect to other end-points, using code that's already tested.

"Re-router" (or "load balancer") needed: Probably not going to be an issue initially. However, it will probably become an issue later. Depending on your overall design and server OS, using UDP may actually become an asset here. UDP packet arrives at the load balancer, dispatched to the right backend and that could then in theory send back a reply with the source IP of the load balancer.

An alternative would be to have a "session broker". The client makes an initial connection to a well-known endpoint, says "I am a client, tell me where my profile, physics, what-have0-you servers are", the broker considers the current load, possibly the location of the client and other things that may make sense and the client then connects to the relevant backends on its own. The downside of this is that it's harder (not impossible, but harder) to silently migrate an ongoing session to a new backend, when there's a load-balancer in the way, this can be done essentially-transparently.

Comment: 1. "UDP vs TCP" - in my case I don't have an opportunity to make use of unreliable data sending so I chose TCP and my question is not about that. 2. Of course I want to be able to run servers seperately. But should I reroute or can I just allow client to connect directly? 3. But **why** "load balancer" is needed? What are the reasons?

Comment: @vlad I have expanded on it. In the question you explicitly say "don't know" to UDP vs TCP, so I thought it was worth pointing out that TCP really isn't suitable for anything that's approaching real-time (typically, a gap of "no info" is better than arbritary delay due to a lost packet and the following time-out before retransmission happens).

Comment: Are there any downsides with "session broker" solution? It seems to be the best choice.

Comment: Don't think that I didn't read your answer, migrating complexity doesn't seems to be a downside for me. It's pretty natural to tell a client where to connect next when he changes location, etc.